# IE is continously maximizing and minimizing when test suite executes

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-8, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using
Selenium standalone server - 2.25.0
IE - 8.0.7601.17514 (64 - bit edition)
IEDriverServer.exe - 2.28.0 (64-bit)
OS - Windows 7 professional
Java - SDK7

I'm using below code to launch IE and run a simple test.

```
    WebDriver driver = null;
    DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = null;
    ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    if (ieCapabilities != null) {
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
    }
    driver.get("http://www.yebhi.com/");
    // driver.findElement(By.id("anchSighin")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul/li/a/div/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[80]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/a"))
            .click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[5]/div[4]/div/div[4]/a")).click();
    driver.switchTo().frame(2);
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtMoblogin")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtMoblogin")).sendKeys("ghfghghf");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtMobPass")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtMobPass")).sendKeys("hfghgh");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
```

By using above code i was able to launch and run the test, but with a problem.
The actual problem is `the browser is continuously maximizing and minimizing until the test suite get finished.`

I am struggling with this issue for more than a week. I don't know weather it is a bug or not. If it is a bug please resolve me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you (either explicitly or via methods in your framework) taking screenshots of the browser along the way?

Comment: @Jim: yes, i am taking screenshots using this way. `scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driverOne).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, "myPath");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IE driver is resizing the IE window because you are taking screenshots. It WebDriver, screenshots are, by definition, of the full page. However, in order to take a screenshot of the full page without scrolling (which would screw up absolutely positioned elements), you have to be able to render the full page in IE. The only way to get the full page to render is to resize the IE window so that the full page is visible without scrolling. So, the IE driver does the resize automatically for the screenshot API call, then restores the window to the state it was in before the call.

Comment: Please clarify me if i am wrong. While minimizing and maximizing(resizing) the window is there any chance to loose the focus from IE. Why i am asking mean while running my test some steps get failed repeatedly. But it run perfectly in FF and chrome for many times.

Comment: Not generally. The window manipulation done during screenshot handling doesn't normally cause the window to lose focus, but anything is possible. Earlier versions of the IEDriverServer.exe would have problems sending the IE window into the background during certain actions (`clear()` being one of them), but that was resolved in 2.26.1 of IEDriverServer.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jim. you saved me a lot of time. Is there any solution to overcome this issue? Simply say, i want to take a screenshot of every action without resizing the window.

Comment: Unfortunately no, not with IE. it's a limitation of the browser's rendering, not of WebDriver.

Comment: Interesting.  If you need to screenshot without the 'resizing' side effect, you can use Sikuli api .

Comment: @djangofan This will be fine if all you care about is the current view port. If you want the entire page rendered, Sikuli won't help you here.

Comment: @JimEvans - i here ya.  fyi, there is also a headless "ghostdriver" on Github that can take screenshots without this affect.

Comment: @JimEvans Is there a way to suppress resizing in case I want to take screenshot of viewport only?